# Confluent control center won't give a response trying to create a Connect Source

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to add a jdbc connect source through Confluent Control Center. I filled in all mandatory tasks, similar connector seems to work when I run it from the shell. When I hit Continue in the screen nothing seems to happen, it doesn't give any hints about the error non. Is there any log or so I can find out what is going on with it?

Comment: "Is there any log " -- Yes, there is a server log on disk. There are also Javascript console logs

Comment: Where can I find the log which is generated when I try to attempt to create a source connector using Confluent control center?

Comment: There is  not a log when you generate. There is a whole server log for all of control center. It is configured in the start up script. Which depends on your OS / installation pattern